# Does Rapid Metamagic reduce the time of a spell cast using Metamagic song?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, metamagic, spellcasting

In the description of **Metamagic Song** from *Races of Stone* it includes the line, emphasis mine:

> Applying metamagic spontaneously using this method increases the casting time of the spell *normally.*

This confirms that the increased time for applying metamagic to an spontaneously cast spell still applies.

If you didn’t use **Metamagic Song** you can use **Rapid Metamagic** to reduce this to “its normal casting time”.

Can you still use **Rapid Metamagic** if you use **Metamagic Song** to payoff the cost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep.  Metamagic Song says "I increase casting time in exactly the same way that normal spontaneous metamagic increases casting time."  It's explicitly *not* mucking with normal spontaneous metamagic casting time adjustments that in any way.  Rapid Metamagic then removes the slowdown, as is normal for spontaneous metamagic under Rapid Metamagic.  It doesn't even matter which one you consider to be more specific/general.